# How to setup cucumberjs with phantomjs

Tags: cucumber, phantomjs

Anyone has experience for setting cucumberjs with phantomjs?
Any related resource will be helpful. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm -g install phantomjs

var client= webdriverjs.remote({ desiredCapabilities: {browserName: 'phantomjs'},logLevel:verbose'});
```

Answer (score 0):

There are not many resources out there about it yet. A few people have been using Phantomjs with Cucumber.js and there are some discussions about it on the [Cukes list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/cukes/phantomjs).

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There is a library Hardy.io that uses Cucumber to drive Selenium based CSS tests - http://hardy.io/.

This doesn't actually run Cucumber *within* PhantomJS, but rather runs Cucumber tests within Node, and uses Selenium Webdriver for introspection of values.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber.js example running tests in PhantomJS https://github.com/patrickarlt/cucumberjs-example